# Android BroadcastReceiver on host Access Point

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi, wifimanager

i've created an app that creates an Access Point with the following code:

```
            WifiConfiguration netConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
            netConfig.SSID = mySSID
            netConfig.preSharedKey = myPass;
            configWifiConfiguration(netConfig);
            return (boolean) method.invoke(wifiManager, netConfig, true); // true
```

it created the access point successfully and the client is now able to connect to it.
In the client i created a broadcast receiver to know when the connection is successfully established.
The client code is:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if ( WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

        } else if (WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

        }
    }
```

with this receiver i can know when the connection is successfull. My problem is that i cant do the same with the host. I need to know when a device connects, so i can start the information transfer.
i want to create a receiver on the host to know when a device connect's to it.
How can i do that?
I tried with actions on WifiP2pManager and ConnectionManager class's but nothing works.
Is there a way of knowing when a device connect's to the host?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if ( "android.net.wifi.WIFI_AP_STATE_CHANGED".equals(action)) 
    {

    }
}
```